# I don't understand the meaning of the last sentence. “He held out his palms as if to have them read”

Tags: meaning

A thin dark man in a dirty caftan materialized and spoke to us in a lengthy nasal language. He held out his palms as if to have them read.

Comment: Have you tried Googling [define "read palm"](https://www.google.co.uk/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=9LTfVIr6KaHj8weo-4GQBQ&gws_rd=ssl#q=define+%22read+palm%22)? Which might prompt you to Google [define "palm reader"](https://www.google.co.uk/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=9LTfVIr6KaHj8weo-4GQBQ&gws_rd=ssl#q=define+%22palm+reader%22)

Comment: Really? This is a question?

Comment: Please don't post [the same question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/49738/i-dont-understand-the-meaning-of-the-last-sentence-he-held-out-his-palms-as-i) on multiple SE sites

Comment: The sentence is actually quite complex. It seems to me that a considerable amount of knowledge would be required (certainly on the part of an English learner) before we could expect someone to know that searching for "read palm" is a good strategy. The OP gets a suggestion to ask the question at ELL, only to be chastized for asking in two places. I don't even know the best procedure for relocating a question, especially if there have been answers or comments. @Bl Your comment strikes me as a meanspirited attack. Geez! :)

Comment: @Jim Reynolds "I soon found the example sentence 'In a tent an old gypsy woman was reading palms.' at [CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/palm), but what does 'read palm/s' mean?" would show reasonable research. ELU is not aimed at learners.

Answer (score 1):

It refers to palmistry or palm reading.

It probably means with palms outstretched and facing upward, as suggested in these images:

https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTgeJOsNAg3e8nZywGFrPjiRNJznyvqDBV3EDlV5GD7zGgIsw-JFA

https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTd8qE1-DYgIXB-MeCRpT41Oj7kBEqDuPTUg5odj_Ui26o2TEpRUA

https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS1rmqoqp47PuoE87SFmBbwTdZb5Tky4hof8_jRTjhiy_pmhekl